# How to have eval use the local scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to writ a function that will loop through a number of product elements, inside a $products jquery object.

For each product, I want to check if its attribute data brand equals any of the brands the user has selected. So, it loops through the the brands that have been selected and creates a string. Then I'm trying to use eval() to convert that string into a conditional expression for an if statement.

The reason I'm doing it this way is because there are going to be filters for other stuff: Product finishes, styles, etc. And also because the filters are dynamic coming from the database and they will change over time.

```
//Set Products and selected Bands Jquery Objects
var $products = $('#product-list li');
var $selectedBrands = $('#filters li:checked');
// Loop through the products
$products.each(function(index, element){
    var $this = $(this);
    var hide = true;
    var brandsString = '';
    // loop through the selected brands
    $selectedBrands.each(function(index2, element2){
        // Create a string to use as a conditional
        brandsString += '$(element).attr("data-brand") == $(element2).val()';
        if($selectedBrands.length != index2 + 1){  
            brandsString += ' || ';
        }   
    });
    // This is where things don't work out. I get the error that element2 is undefined
    console.log(eval(brandsString));
    if(eval(brandsString)){
        hide = false;
    }
});
```

I tried declaring element2 outside the inside loop, but that returned false on all the products.

Comment: BTW, the reason I did all of this instead of using .filter('[data-brand=x]') is because some products fit multiple styles

Comment: this is the wrong way to go about it. Instead of constructing an expression connected with `||`, use `$selectedBrands.some()` to test each condition from the array.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna read up on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use evil `eval`.

Instead, wouldn't the following be easier?

```
var b = false; // boolean
$selectedBrands.each(function(index2, element2){
    b = b || $(element).attr("data-brand") == $(element2).val();
});
console.log(b);
```

But wait! There is [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var b = [].some.call($selectedBrands, function(element2, index2){
    return $(element).attr("data-brand") == $(element2).val();
});
console.log(b);
```